# Работа с PDF-файлами в C# не используя сторонние библиотеки

Tags: c#, pdf

Появился такой вопросик. В C# же можно работать с PDF файлами, а как то можно с ними работать без сторонних библиотек, я вот просто заметил что в Windows есть такая штука как Microsoft Print to PDF, может можно как то подключиться к ним и попробовать поработать с PDF-файлами?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: что такое `поработать с PDF-файлами` ?

Comment: т.е. создать его и сохранить.

Comment: Принтер не поможет создать pdf файл и наполнить его каким-либо содержимым. Можно разбираться со структурой и форматом pdf файлов. Можно создать docx файл, оформить как вам надо и преобразовать в pdf.

Comment: "Хочу автомобиль, у меня есть крышка от багажника (вот фото), может можно как-то заставить её поехать?"